# Bounds for the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial of a graph

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a $n$-vertex graph and $A_G$ its adjacency matrix with charachteristic polynomial $$p_G(x) = x^n + a_1 x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_{n-1}x + a_n\,. $$

It is well known that $$(-1)^i a_i = \sum (-1)^{r(H)} 2^{s(H)} \quad (1)$$ where $r,s$ are the [rank/co-rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(graph_theory)) functions and the sum is over all subgraphs of $G$ comprised of $i$ vertices and having only cycles and $K_2$ as their connected components.

Equality $(1)$ implies that $$ |a_i| \leq {n \choose i} 2^{\lfloor i/2 \rfloor }\,.$$

What I am wondering is

> Are there any better known bounds for $|a_i|$?

Surely, one can get better estimates using $(1)$ but given how fundamental this problem is, I suppose there are already some known results in this direction?